# Sorting an array based on the order of another

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, scope

I have one array with data objects:

```
[{height: '5 feet'}, {name: 'john'}, {'hair-color': 'brown'}]
```

And another with the order those objects should follow in:

```
['name', 'height', 'hair-color']
```

So to sort the first array I was trying to use the sort method which compares the arrays elements two at a time and determines which should be ordered first based on a criterion, mine being the order in which each object's key appears in the second array. The problem is that the callback used by the sort method is only passed the two elements so I cannot compare them to anything in the second array because it is out of scope of the callback. Any help with this would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `{hair-color: 'brown'}` is not a valid form of object declaration. If you have a space or a dash in your label, you have to wrap it in quotes: `{'hair-color': 'brown'}`

Comment: @Aleks G This is all within a larger javascript object so they are both attached to 'this'. So it would seem to me that declaring the second array globally would be bad practice, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that will do that.  I must say that your first data structure is a bit odd because there's no easy way to get the key in each object in that first array.  But, I worked up a funky way to do it and it does sort:

```
var source = [{height: '5 feet'}, {name: 'john'}, {'hair-color': 'brown'}];
var desiredOrder = ['name', 'height', 'hair-color'];

function sortBy(src, order) {

    // assumes both src and order are the same length and every item in source has a
    // matching item in order and there are no empty objects in src

    // this is a funky function who's job it is to find the first key in the
    // object.  Why the OP used a data structure like this, I have no idea!
    // It makes no sense to me because it's next to impossible to use in real life
    function findKey(obj) {
        for (var i in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                return(i);
            }
        }
    }

    // make an object that has each of the keys in it with the sort order as the value
    var sortHash = {};
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
        sortHash[order[i]] = i;
    }

    var result = new Array(src.length);
    var key;
    for (i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
        key = findKey(src[i]);
        result[sortHash[key]] = src[i];
    }
    return(result);
}

var result = sortBy(source, desiredOrder);
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Y8xnY/.